# Why does the method what_are_you output nothing? Syntax mistake?

Tags: python, class, methods

In this program the output is not what I would expect:

```py
class example(object):
    def __init__(self, foo,bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar  = bar
    def what_are_you():
        print(foo,bar)
        print("This doesn't work either")

a = example("aaa","bbb")
a.what_are_you
#should return "aaa bbb"
print(a.what_are_you)
print(a.foo,a.bar)
```

Instead it outputs nothing. This is the whole output:

```
<bound method example.what_are_you of <__main__.example object at 0x000002A9574B4710>>
aaa bbb

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.041 s
```

Comment: you have to use `self.` in `def what_are_you(self)` and `print(self.foo, self.bar)`. And you forgot `()` in `a.what_are_you()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see now, you're printing stuff, not `return`ing stuff, so you might need to use:

```
a.what_are_you()
```

And in your function, you need to use `self` to get the variable:

```
def what_are_you(self):
    print(self.foo,self.bar)
    print("This doesn't work either")
```

Comment: change to `def what_are_you(self):`

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh good catch man, thanks

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh wow this was the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Heisenberg also, look in my function

Comment: @U9-Forward Thanks, that was part of the problem aswell

Answer (score 1):

By not including parentheses, you're printing the function object, not calling the function. To call the function, put parentheses after it.

```
print(a.what_are_you())
```

will print the value of `what_are_you()` (whatever is in the `return` statement)

Comment: That returns:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Orion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\chimp.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(a.what_are_you())
TypeError: what_are_you() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given